# AWS Console and Request context

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Are requests made from **AWS Console** automatically signed? For example - Once an authenticated entity (a user) tries to create an S3 bucket **from Console**, does the API request get signed automatically similar to SDK/CLI requests Or does the concept of signing an API request (automatically) not apply to **the Console** at all?

Does the AWS enforcement code check whether the entity is authenticated for **each request** made via the AWS Console or is the authentication check bypassed because the entity authenticated by logging into the console first before it made the request? - Is this authentication check for **every request** only for CLI/SDK and HTTP API calls and not for Console requests?

Comment: While your session is ok, you are good to do anything on the console.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AWS checks the authentication status of entity for each request. For every request you make on the console you will be redirected to https://us-west-2.signin.aws.amazon.com/oauth?SignatureVersion=4&X-Amz-Algorithm=A...(all the required params here) where the entity's authentication will be validated and gets redirected to respective resource that the entity is trying to access.

Comment: Thanks Praveen - AWS documentation says that "When you use the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI) or one of the AWS SDKs to make requests to AWS, these tools automatically sign the requests for you with the access key that you specify when you configure the tools" - How does requests made from Console get signed ? as they do not have access key and instead has a username and password. My question is if Console requests get signed with username and password?

Comment: Once you login to AWS Console, you get a cryptographically signed code(with expiry) which will be attached to all the subsequent requests you make. So for every request that's made from console AWS will verify this code(both for authentication and authorization) and redirect you based on the validity of that code. This is the standard OAuth flow. This is based on my understanding.